# div always after content and always on bottom

Tags: html, css

i have this schema:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="content">some text</div>

    <footer> my footer things </footer>

</div>
```

and my css:

```
body {
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background:url(../imagens/fundo_cima.jpg) top center no-repeat;
    background-color: #bac8e3;
    color:#000;
    font-size:12px;
    height:100%;    
}

#container{
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

#content{
    width:990px;
    min-height:526px;
    margin:0 auto;  
}

footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:231px;
    background:url(../imagens/fundo_baixo.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
```

My problem: In small resolutions (1024x768), the footer is hovering the `content` div, and in big resolutions, this works well.... what i need to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had good luck using this tutorial/code. http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put a margin on the `#content` div to make space for the footer.

```
#content{
    width:990px;
    min-height:526px;
    margin:0 auto 231px auto;  
}
```

Absolutely-positioned elements like the footer will naturally hover over the rest of content. If you want to avoid this effect, the easiest way is to make other elements leave space for them via padding or margin.